# Visual flow: Passing a visual-flow variable to apex controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, visual-workflow

Is there any way to pass a variable created in visual flow to an apex controller?

Please provide a code example.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. The flow variable has to be input/output or output only. see my answer here http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160136/how-to-combine-vf-page-with-visual-flow-to-upload-file/160263#160263 for an example with varUpload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="testController">
    <flow:interview name="nameOfYourVisualFlow" interview="{!visualFlow}" />
</apex:page>
```

controller:

```
public class testController {
    public Flow.Interview.nameOfYourVisualFlow visualFlow { get; set; }

    public Opportunity getVarOpportunity() {
        if (visualFlow == null) { 
            return null; 
        }
        return visualFlow.varOpportunity;
    }
}
```

Important the varOpportunity must be set as output field in visual flow.