# Visual flow - adding visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, visual-workflow

How do I add a custom visualforce page in a visual flow project?

I have the following code:

Visualforce page:

```
    <apex:page controller="DeliveryDocumentVisualFlowController">
        <flow:interview name="Wizard_Delivery_Document" interview="{!myFlow}">
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </apex:page>
```

I cannot see this custom visualforce page in my visual flow. The only way I can see it is indirectly, meaning, I need to use a controller and set the annotation @InvocableMethod.

I hope there is another way.

Comment: Do you mean being able to diplay the visual force page within the flow by getting to it from the flow builder?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to add a Visualforce page within a flow, e.g. there is no way to see it as an option in the Flow Builder. The only method to switch to visualforce is using a page as a wrapper for the flow and passing control to it by setting a variable value within the flow, which there is an example of [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160136/how-to-combine-vf-page-with-visual-flow-to-upload-file/160263#160263).