# Upload attachments and send with Email

Tags: apex, visualforce, send-email

I`m have build below visualforce page which allows our portal users to send emails. Page works fine, however now I want to add a functionality to allow users to upload the attachment and send with email. I have went through lot of resources online but cant find the solution. Can someone please help?

```
public class sendEmailStdCon {

    private final Case c;

    //Case fields
     public String Caseno { get; set; }
     public String CaseRecType { get; set; }
     public String CaseStatus { get; set; }
     public String CaseSubject { get; set; }
    public string threadID { get; set; }
    public string refNumber   { get; set; }

    public String subject { get; set; }
    public String body { get; set; }
    public String addresses { get; set; }
    public String BodyofEmail { get; set; }
    public String BccAddress { get; set; }
    public String ccAddress { get; set; }
    public String ToAddress { get; set; }


    public   String orgEmails {get;set;}



    datetime currenttime =  System.now();

    public sendEmailStdCon(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

        Case c = [SELECT id, CaseNumber,Status ,Subject, Email_Case_Ref__c , RecordType.Name from Case where id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

            Caseno = c.CaseNumber;
         CaseRecType = c.RecordType.Name;
            CaseStatus = c.Status;
            CaseSubject = C.Subject;
           refNumber = c.Email_Case_Ref__c;     

        EmailMessage e = [ SELECT id, FromName,CcAddress, BccAddress,ToAddress , Subject, TextBody, FromAddress from EmailMessage WHERE 
                          ParentId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')  ORDER BY MessageDate DESC Limit 1  ];



        BodyofEmail = e.TextBody;
        Subject = e.Subject;
        BccAddress =  Userinfo.getUserEmail();
        ccAddress = e.CcAddress;
        addresses = e.FromAddress; 
        ToAddress = e.ToAddress;
    }







    public Case getCase() {
        return c;
    }

    public PageReference send() {

                  system.debug('orgEmails: ' + orgEmails);


      OrgWideEmailAddress[] owea = [select Id from OrgWideEmailAddress where Address = :orgEmails];


        // Define the email
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 



        String[] toAddresses = ToAddress.split(';', 0);

        // Sets the paramaters of the email
        email.setSubject( subject + ' ' + refNumber);
        email.setToAddresses( toAddresses );

        if (ccAddress != null && ccAddress.trim() != '' ) {
        String[] cccAddresses =ccAddress.split(';', 0);
        email.setCcAddresses( cccAddresses );
            }

        email.setPlainTextBody( BodyofEmail );



                if (BccAddress != null && BccAddress.trim() != '' ) {
        String[] BccAddresses =BccAddress.split(';', 0);
        email.setCcAddresses( BccAddresses );
            }


        if ( owea.size() > 0 ) {
        email.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owea.get(0).Id);
        }



        // Sends the email
        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = 
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});   


             //   EmailMessage E = New EmailMessage () ;
            //  e.


        return null;
    }
}
```

VF:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Case" extensions="sendEmailStdCon">


    <apex:messages />
    <apex:pageBlock title="Send an Email to Your Representatives">
        <p>Fill out information below and click on "Send" button send an email.</p>
        <br />
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2"> 
            <apex:outputText label="Case Number" value="{!Caseno}"> </apex:outputText>
            <apex:outputText label="Case Record Type" value="{!CaseRecType}"> </apex:outputText>
            <apex:outputText label="Status" value="{!CaseStatus}"> </apex:outputText>
            <apex:outputText label="Subject" value="{!CaseSubject}"> </apex:outputText>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:form >


            <br /><br />

            <apex:outputLabel value="To" for="To"/>:<br />     
            <apex:inputText value="{!ToAddress}" id="to" maxlength="500" style="width: 500px;" />
            <br /><br />

            <apex:outputLabel value="CC" for="CC"/>:<br />     
            <apex:inputText value="{!ccAddress}" id="cc" maxlength="500" style="width: 500px;" />
            <br /><br />

            <apex:outputLabel value="Bcc" for="Bcc"/>:<br />     
            <apex:inputText value="{!Bccaddress}" id="Bcc" maxlength="500" style="width: 500px;"  />
            <br /><br />


            <apex:outputLabel value="Subject" for="Subject"/>:<br />     
            <apex:inputText value="{!subject}" id="Subject" maxlength="500" style="width: 500px;" />
            <br /><br />


            <apex:outputLabel value="Body" for="Body"/>:<br />     
            <apex:inputTextarea value="{!BodyofEmail}" id="Body"  rows="10" cols="80" style="width:550px;height:500px"   />           
            <br /><br /><br />
            <apex:commandButton value="Send Email" action="{!send}" /> 
        </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the debug log or specific problems with the code behaviour or is it you just need the code for allowing an attachment to be added? My answer here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160136/how-to-combine-vf-page-with-visual-flow-to-upload-file/160263#160263 does include VF and the controller to allow file attachments by the user.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Im trying to use your controller and VF page but it keeps giving me an error "Invalid type: my_flow" . If I try to upload a file with my current code, Im getting view size error. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: just take out the flow references as that is only required if you are using the VF page as a wrapper on a Visual Flow that needs to upload a file.

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to add tag to accept file

I had used HTML tag for this

in javascript you can get file and sent to server side

at server side you will get file in blob format, the add this file to email attachment like this.

```
public void send(blob attachment){

    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
    efa.setFileName('attachment');
    efa.setBody(attachment);

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
    email.setSubject( subject );
    email.setToAddresses( toAddresses );
    email.setPlainTextBody( body );

    email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});

    // Sends the email
    Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = 
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email})

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add attachment to your mail please below code I had updated your code

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Case" extensions="sendEmailStdCon">
<apex:messages />
<apex:pageBlock title="Send an Email to Your Representatives">
    <p>Fill out information below and click on "Send" button send an email.</p>
    <br />
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2"> 
        <apex:outputText label="Case Number" value="{!Caseno}"> </apex:outputText>
        <apex:outputText label="Case Record Type" value="{!CaseRecType}"> </apex:outputText>
        <apex:outputText label="Status" value="{!CaseStatus}"> </apex:outputText>
        <apex:outputText label="Subject" value="{!CaseSubject}"> </apex:outputText>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:form >
        <br /><br />
        <apex:outputLabel value="To" for="To"/>:<br />     
        <apex:inputText value="{!ToAddress}" id="to" maxlength="500" style="width: 500px;" />
        <br /><br />
        <apex:outputLabel value="CC" for="CC"/>:<br />     
        <apex:inputText value="{!ccAddress}" id="cc" maxlength="500" style="width: 500px;" />
        <br /><br />
        <apex:outputLabel value="Bcc" for="Bcc"/>:<br />     
        <apex:inputText value="{!Bccaddress}" id="Bcc" maxlength="500" style="width: 500px;"  />
        <br /><br />
        <apex:outputLabel value="Subject" for="Subject"/>:<br />     
        <apex:inputText value="{!subject}" id="Subject" maxlength="500" style="width: 500px;" />
        <br /><br />
        <apex:outputLabel value="Body" for="Body"/>:<br />     
        <apex:inputTextarea value="{!BodyofEmail}" id="Body"  rows="10" cols="80" style="width:550px;height:500px"   />           
        <br /><br /><br />
        <apex:outputLabel value="File Name" for="fileName"/>
        <apex:inputText value="{!attachment.name}" id="fileName"/>
        <apex:outputLabel value="File" for="file"/>
        <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}" filename="{!attachment.name}" id="file"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Send Email" action="{!send}" /> 
    </apex:form>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

---

```
public class sendEmailStdCon {

    private final Case c;

    //Case fields
    public String Caseno { get; set; }
    public String CaseRecType { get; set; }
    public String CaseStatus { get; set; }
    public String CaseSubject { get; set; }
    public string threadID { get; set; }
    public string refNumber   { get; set; }
    public String subject { get; set; }
    public String body { get; set; }
    public String addresses { get; set; }
    public String BodyofEmail { get; set; }
    public String BccAddress { get; set; }
    public String ccAddress { get; set; }
    public String ToAddress { get; set; }
    public   String orgEmails {get;set;}
    datetime currenttime =  System.now();
    public Attachment attachment {
        get {
            if (attachment == null)
                attachment = new Attachment();
            return attachment;
        }
        set;
    }

    public sendEmailStdCon(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

        Case c = [SELECT id, CaseNumber,Status ,Subject, Email_Case_Ref__c , RecordType.Name from Case where id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

            Caseno = c.CaseNumber;
         CaseRecType = c.RecordType.Name;
            CaseStatus = c.Status;
            CaseSubject = C.Subject;
           refNumber = c.Email_Case_Ref__c;     

        EmailMessage e = [ SELECT id, FromName,CcAddress, BccAddress,ToAddress , Subject, TextBody, FromAddress from EmailMessage WHERE 
                          ParentId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')  ORDER BY MessageDate DESC Limit 1  ];



        BodyofEmail = e.TextBody;
        Subject = e.Subject;
        BccAddress =  Userinfo.getUserEmail();
        ccAddress = e.CcAddress;
        addresses = e.FromAddress; 
        ToAddress = e.ToAddress;
    }




 public Case getCase() {
        return c;
    }

    public PageReference send() {

        List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();
        Messaging.Emailfileattachment attachmentForMail = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
        attachmentForMail.setFileName(attachment.Name);
        attachmentForMail.setBody(attachment.Body);
        fileAttachments.add(attachmentForMail);

        OrgWideEmailAddress[] owea = [select Id from OrgWideEmailAddress where Address = :orgEmails];
        // Define the email
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
        String[] toAddresses = ToAddress.split(';', 0);
        // Sets the paramaters of the email
        email.setSubject( subject + ' ' + refNumber);
        email.setToAddresses( toAddresses );
        if (ccAddress != null && ccAddress.trim() != '' ) {
            String[] cccAddresses =ccAddress.split(';', 0);
            email.setCcAddresses( cccAddresses );
        }
        email.setPlainTextBody( BodyofEmail );
        if (BccAddress != null && BccAddress.trim() != '' ) {

            String[] BccAddresses =BccAddress.split(';', 0);
            email.setCcAddresses( BccAddresses );
        }
        if ( owea.size() > 0 ) {

            email.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owea.get(0).Id);
        }
        email.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);
        // Sends the email
        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});   
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Please do not leave a signature under your posts; that's just noise and and a link to your profile is automatically added by the system anyway.

Comment: @Amol ... I`m trying to use code above but keep getting this Error: "Maximum view state size limit (135KB) exceeded. Actual view state size for this page was 149.188KB "

Comment: @Wendy...Hello it seems to be like that you are trying to attach file which has large  size....thats why view state is getting  hit....In this case you can pass your attachment through javascript...so that  attachment size will not get calculated in view state of your page. - Amol